# Store Array of Record in JSON

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe3, superobject

How can an array of record be stored in JSON via SuperObject library. For example..

```
type
  TData = record
    str: string;
    int: Integer;
    bool: Boolean;
    flt: Double;
  end;

var
DataArray: Array[0..100] of TData;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use the superobject Marshalling `TSuperRTTIContext`

```delphi
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  superobject,
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TData = record
    str : string;
    int : Integer;
    bool : Boolean;
    flt : Double;
  end;

  TDataArray = Array [0 .. 100] of TData;

procedure Test;
var
  DataArray : TDataArray;
  so :        ISuperObject;
  ctx :       TSuperRttiContext;
begin
  ctx := TSuperRttiContext.Create;
  try
    so := ctx.AsJson<TDataArray>( DataArray );
  finally
    ctx.Free;
  end;
  Writeln( so.AsJson );
end;

begin
  try
    Test;
  except
    on E : Exception do
      Writeln( E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message );
  end;

  ReadLn;

end.
```

Comment: The SuperObject help file has this exact example (maybe not same code but same concept with RTTI)

Comment: @JerryDodge Maybe because this is the way to go? If this case is documented, why should it be different?

Comment: I didn't say it should be different, I was just saying that because OP could have simply read SuperObject's help file which comes with the library rather than asking here. Exact same solution is already explained there.

Comment: @JerryDodge +1 Sorry for misinterpreting your comment, but that fits to some question ;o)

Answer (score 3):

Make it a string first.

```
Your array:
//Array[0] := 'Apple';
//Array[1] := 'Orange';
//Array[2] := 'Banana';
myArrayAsStr := '"MyArray": [{ "1": "' + Array[0] +'", "2": "' + Array[1] +'"}';
```

Then you can just make it into JSON with `SO(myArrayAsStr)`
You can always generate your array as string in a different procedure but I think thats the way to do it.

Ill keep checking if there is an easier way ;)

EDIT:
SuperObject also has the following function:
`function SA(const Args: array of const): ISuperObject; overload;`
You will be able to convert that to a string again and add it in the total JSON string.

Comment: Just to note: The result `"MyArray": [{ "1": "Apple", "2": "Orange"}` is **not** a valid JSON string. It should be `{"MyArray": [{ "1": "Apple", "2": "Orange"}]}` or even `[{ "1": "Apple", "2": "Orange"}]`